# Returning two values from combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

In my program I have stored values in list. I need to return two of these values from one combo box. I have searched in internet but couldn't find the answer. Please give me some tips.
Here is my code:

Values in List:

```
public class ActualCurrencyBoxData
{
    public string displayValue { get; private set; }
    public decimal currencyCourse { get; set; }       
    public int currencyConverter { get; set; }

    public ActualCurrencyBoxData( string ncurrencyName, string ncurrencyCode, decimal ncurrencyCourse, int ncurrencyConverter)
    {
        displayValue = ncurrencyName +" (" +ncurrencyCode+ ")";
        currencyCourse = ncurrencyCourse;          
        currencyConverter = ncurrencyConverter;           
    }

}
```

I was able to return only one value (actualCurrencyCourse, I need also currencyConverter):

```
List<ActualCurrencyBoxData> checkBoxVal = new List<ActualCurrencyBoxData>();

public void CurrencyBoxLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    comboBox.ItemsSource = checkBoxVal;
    comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "displayValue";
    comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "currencyCourse";                                
}

private void Count_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
    actualCurrencyCourse =  ActualCurrencyBox.SelectedValue.ToString());  
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedItem` property instead to get the selected item's object:

```
private void Count_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
    actualCurrencyCourse = ((ActualCurrencyBoxData)ActualCurrencyBox.SelectedItem).currencyCourse;
    actualCurrencyConverter = ((ActualCurrencyBoxData)ActualCurrencyBox.SelectedItem).currencyConverter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried this one and get this error: ActualCurrencyBoxData' does not contain a definition for 'CurrencyConverter' and no extension method 'CurrencyConverter' accepting a first argument of type 'ActualCurrencyBoxData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: woops, looks like I misread your property name's casing. I typically use upper camel case (aka. Pascal case) for class properties. Habits are hard to break :) Correct the casing (as I just did in my first post) to match yours. Also, if you are interested: http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase

Comment: Oh, I can't believe that I missed it. It work's, thank you I will have a look at it.